# How can I create a poster of size larger than A0?

Tags: posters, baposter, a0poster

How can I change this through the argument:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} ?
```

Is there something I can replace a0paper with that would give me a bigger poster? Really, anything bigger is fine so that I can fit just a few more lines/images without getting a rearranged/re-proportioned poster.

Comment: `\usepackage[paperwidth=1ly,paperheight=1ly]{geometry}`  Is this large enough?

Comment: Please let me know whether you were able to find a publisher/printer for this ;_)

Comment: standalone with minipage (for \textwidth) can create an undefinitely long document.